# How to use map to make rest api calls in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark

I am trying to use map to make put rest api calls on a `rdd` like following:

```
def put(params, payload):
  
  url = "https://{}/{}".format(server, params)
  headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
  
  response = requests.request("PUT", url, headers=headers, data = payload) 
  return response.status_code

df.select("params", "payload").rdd.map(lambda x, y: put(x, y)).collect()
```

But I am getting an error:

> org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: 'TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'payload''

It seems like the lambda function didn't get the second parameter `payload`, not sure why. Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code below is culprit:

```
df.select("params", "payload").rdd.map(lambda x, y: put(x, y)).collect()
```

You cannot unpack dataframe in lambda function. This is the correct one:

```
df.select("params", "payload").rdd.map(lambda row: put(row[0], row[1])).collect()
```

Comment: Do you happen to know how to merge the response back to the rdd or df? I would like to map the response back to each request (per row).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried so many times to upvote your answer, not sure what happened, stack overflow won't show it. Could be a bug?

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to add a comment to Nihad's answer. So adding an answer to Nihad's answer and the follow up question on how to merge the response back to the DF.

You could possibly do something like below

```
df_new = df.select("params", "payload").rdd.map(lambda row: [row[0],
                                                             row[1],
                                                             put(row[0], row[1])]
                                                )
                                       .toDF()
```

This way you can link the original data to the response.

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to add response to the dataframe you would have to register the put method with udf and use it in withColumn method to dataframe.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

putUdf = udf(put, StringType())

df = df.withColumn("response", putUdf(df.params, df.payload))
```

This would create a new column called response and fills put ouput in it.

Comment: Thanks for response. I did try to use UDF, but the performance was not so good. It took around 6 mins to run 1 row (and 1 row took the same amount of time as 100 rows). That is why I tried to explore other routs. The MAP on RDD is what I found out. Not sure why using MAP on RDD is run much faster than UDF on DateFrame. Will you provide more insight?